# What can I use for key exchange?

Tags: key-exchange

I am trying to send AES keys from one computer to another, but I need to provide some form of attestation of the key's provenance. How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are implementing this for commercial purpose, respectively if security is crucial, then there are standards and somewhat "best practices" (like the [TLS Protocol Specs](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8446#section-4.1)).

In general when you want two parties to agree on a shared secret key, some kind of Key-Exchange like Diffie-Hellman or ECDH is applied. Often this goes hand-in-hand with some KDF (key derivation function).

Another approach would be the usage of KEMs (key encapsulation mechanism), but as far as I know these kind of techniques are not widely used (yet! their time will come).

So without further information on your exact problem and use case, I would suggest taking a look into:

- DH   (Diffie-Hellman)
- ECDH (Elliptic Curve Diffie-Hellman)
- KDFs (Key Derivation Functions)
- KEMs (Key Encapsulation Mechanisms)

Note that there are reliable frameworks and libraries out there, which (probably) already implement the stuff that you need.